# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable order"

Tags: vue.js

I use Laravel as an api, I have pass a collection (orders) of object (order) at the view.
I don't no why I can't access to my variable in a simple methods in vue.js ..

```
    props: ['orders'],
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.');
    },
    data() {
        return {
            select: [],
            selected: 'csv',
            options: [
                { text: 'Export CSV', value: 'csv' },
                { text: 'Factures PDF', value: 'pdf' },
                { text: 'Changer de status', value: 'status' },
            ],
            status: '1',
            orders: this.orders,
        }
    },
```

```
    methods: {
      submit() {
        if (this.selected == 'csv') {
          // faire csv
        } else if (this.selected == 'pdf'){
          // faire pdf
        } else {
            for (order in this.orders) {
              console.log(order.id);
            }

            axios.post('/api/admin/commandes/change-status',{
              newStatus:this.status,
              select:this.select
            }).then(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
            })
        }
      }
    },
```

```
error : [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: orders is not defined"
```

The problem is just un the for..in because I can display Orders in the view.

Comment: `orders: this.orders,` is where your issue is. `orders` needs to be an object not a reference to itself. rename your `data` `orders` to something else.

Comment: `data()` is ran very early in your component initialization. It sets the reactive properties (what Vue will listen and react to, throughout the component's lifecycle). At that point, you can't even access previously defined properties in `data()` (i.e: `this.options` in your case), nevermind a property which is just being declared. You probably want to change `orders: this.orders` to `orders: []` and populate `this.orders` later on, in some method.

Comment: @Varcorb @AndreiGheorghiu I have change ``` orders: [] ``` and It's the same error.. I'm little lost with vue.js O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props, data properties and computed properties all need to have unique names. All three are typically accessed via `this.blah` (where `blah` is the name) so if you have two with the same name you'll have difficulty referring to the correct one.

In your case you've got a prop called `orders` and a data property called `orders`. If you need both then they'll need to have different names but if they're just going to have the same value then there's no need to have both. Based on the code you've posted it would seem that you just need the prop and can remove the data property.

None of which really explains the error messages you reported, but it is a problem you should fix before going any further.

There are a couple of problems with this line:

```js
for (order in this.orders)
```

Firstly, you need a `var`, `let` or `const` to declare `order`, otherwise it'll end up being global. I'd suggest `const` unless you've got a good reason to use something else.

I believe that would explain the error message you posted in the title.

Secondly, using `for`/`in` will iterate over the keys of the object/array. It's unlikely that's what you want as `order` will be the property name/index and not the value itself. Given you're trying to access `order.id` I would guess you meant to use `for`/`of` instead?

I struggle to explain what would cause the second error message you posted. I had initially thought it could be because `this.orders` was `undefined` but I don't believe that would cause such a message in the code you posted.